# Local PC cache stays filled with old WordPress Site data

Tags: htaccess, cache

I am developing a new WP site. My client complains that he see old site data like links that refer to old category names. On my PC and other I have no problems with this. On server side there is no cache plugin running. Reason: site is still in development. On my PC and in every browser there is no such problem. Always get the newest page info.

I only use in htaccess file this for Leverage Browser Caching

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On 
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year" 
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month" 
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year" 
</IfModule> 
# Leverage Browser Caching Ninja -- Ends here
```

What can I suggest my customer to do/change his local PC settings so he get always the newest data?

Answer (score 3):

Unsurprisingly so since you tell browser to cache everything for 1 month by default (`ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"`).

You should limit long caching times to static resources and leave pages served by WP out of it.

My go to resource for [`.htaccess` configuration](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/dist/.htaccess) is HTML5 Boilerplate.

It works with WP nicely and correctly excludes web pages from agressive browser caching (`ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"`).

Answer (score 0):

You should never set an expiry for the HTML which is longer then few hours and never set expiry for logged in users at all.

The reason is that while you can cache bust CSS, JS and even images, you just can't do it with HTML as users are accessing html URLs directly and you have no way to instruct them to go to a "fresher" ones.

In you case

```
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
```

Can trigger caching of the HTML for a month, and the lesser problem is when it is cached on the costumers computer, as he can use the browser tools to clear the cache, but if it is cached at any proxy then you will not have any way to clear it and the site will serve stale pages for a month.

In addition to the general problem of cached pages this also have security implications as admin pages might be cache with whatever confidential information they contain and people that do not have read access to the site will be able to read it from the proxy.